# How do I make an SSO Popup in MS Teams App

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

Currently, I've created a new MS Teams *react app*, and:

In the "staticTabs" -> I have a tab that renders our website/app through (I'm assuming iFrame).

SSO is being triggered from our website/app code, so SSO works perfectly on MS Teams *WEBSITE* (since it just loads up a new tab with the SSO login). However, the SSO does not popup on the actual downloadable MS Teams app itself.

How can I get our SSO to popup once a user clicks the tab that hosts our app in an iFrame?

I tried creating a component in the src for the MS teams app that runs SSO using our SSO url.